# Javascript - Programmatically execute method on input of all functions

Tags: javascript, function, methods, preprocessor

I would like to add a parser to a list of functions, for example:

```
var list = {
    function1: function(input){},
    function2: function(input){}
}
```

and I would like that all the `input` params are prepocessed with another function. Is that possible?

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "add a parser to a list of functions"? What are you parsing?

Comment: You are looking for "*decorators*". Read into aspect-oriented programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? It creates a new copy of `funcs` with methods that preapply `f` to their inputs.:

```js
function addPreProcessing(funcs, f) {
    return Object.keys(funcs).reduce(function (o, key) {
        o[key] = function (input) {
            return funcs[key](f(input));
        };
        return o;
    }, {});
}

var list = {
     log: function (input) { snippet.log(input); },
     quadruple: function (input) { return input * 4; }
};

// preprocess all inputs by doubling them
var list2 = addPreProcessing(list, function (input) {
     return input * 2;
});

list2.log(5);                        // logs 10   ( 5 * 2 )
snippet.log(list2.quadruple(1));     // logs 8    ( 1 * 2 * 4)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

And here's a lodash version of the `addPreProcessing` function above:

```
function addPreProcessing(funcs, f) {
    return _.mapValues(funcs, _.flowRight(_.partial(_.flow, f), _.identity));
}
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain? I did my best to answer a very vague question.